# How can I restrict selectable terms in a term reference field to only show those which have been used earlier by the same user?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a node (type = List) with 2 fields, Term Name and Body.
Body is a long text type field and Term Name is a entity reference field, which is a drop down with a list of Term in Vocabulary Vocab.

Let’s say Terms are Term1 and Term2 in Vocab.

My Requirement is:

1. user creates new content Node 1. Term Name field should display all the Terms in Vocabulary Vocab. user selects the Term1 and saves the content.
2. user creates new node Node 2, Term Name field dropdown should display only Term1. as values.

So in short, if there is any node created by a user, Term Name field should contain on term selected in already created node. if there is no node created by user all term names should be displayed.

Any idea how I can achieve this? I am using Drupal 7.x

Comment: hook_form_alter on the node form and then a database query to get all nodes with terms field not empty, get the terms and unset them from the list of terms you get directly from the vocab, and then use the result to re-populate the options.

Comment: I am not a developer, so writing this is code will be difficult. Is there any module which I can use and configure to achieve the result.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question: "user creates new node Node 2, Term Name field dropdown should display only Term1. as values"? Should it say that only Term 2 should be available to be chosen? If yes, then I think this functionality might be covered with Flags  https://www.drupal.org/project/flag when you make the Flag global in settings, and also use the Flag limit module.

Comment: @prkos – I think I misunderstood the question when I edited the title the first time. Fixed it now.

Comment: Ah, so it's not just one term in general, but only for the one user, and other users start with all terms available? That doesn't sound like something that would be available out-of-box, at least I'm not aware of any such solution. Maybe Flag lists can be made to work like that, restricting per user and first term used, with an extra module.

Comment: actually yes, thats the idea. I wish to capture choice of a user and give him that option later always. In my environment, if user selects one option he will not be selecting other option in its life time. I am trying to use multiple view entity reference to achieve this but problem i am facing is all non selected  terms (Term2 in our case) is displayed as blank. However these values are not diplayed in view perview.

Comment: in my last comment i am talking about following issue https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view/issues/2928014